# Filter out / remove elements matching criteria from the end of array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an array of strings. Some of elements are empty, i.e. `''` (there are no `null`, `undefined` or strings containing only white space characters). I need to remove these empty elements, but only from the (right) end of array. Empty elements that come before non-empty elements should remain. If there are only empty strings in array, empty array should be returned.

Below is the code I have so far. It works, but I wonder - is there a way that does not require all these `if`s? Can I do it without creating in-memory copy of array?

```
function removeFromEnd(arr) {
    t = [...arr].reverse().findIndex(e => e !== '');

    if (t === 0) {
        return arr;
    } else if (t === -1) {
        return [];
    } else {
        return arr.slice(0, -1 * t);
    }
}
```

### Test cases

```
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '', 'c']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '']));
```

```
[ 'a', 'b', '', 'c' ]
[ 'a' ]
[ '', '', '', '', 'c' ]
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is using the function **[`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)** along with the **[`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**.

```js
let removeFromEnd = (arr) => arr.reduceRight((a, b) => ((b !== '' || a.length) ? [b, ...a] : a), []);    

console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '', 'c']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tail recursive implementation of `removeFromEnd`. Our implementation:

- does not mutate its input
- does not unnecessarily calculate the `reverse` of the input
- does not unnecessarily search the input using `find` or `findIndex`
- does not iterate thru the input more than once
- does not require `Array.prototype.reduce` or `Array.prototype.reduceRight`
- accepts *any* [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) input – not only Arrays

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const removeFromEnd = ([ x = Empty, ...xs ], cont = identity) =>
  x === Empty
    ? cont ([])
    : removeFromEnd (xs, end =>
        end.length === 0 && x === ''
          ? cont ([])
          : cont ([ x, ...end ]))

console.log (removeFromEnd ([ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '' ]))
// [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c' ]

console.log (removeFromEnd ([ 'a', '', '' ]))
// [ 'a' ]

console.log (removeFromEnd ([ '', '', '', '', 'c' ]))
// [ '', '', '', '', 'c' ]

console.log (removeFromEnd ([ '', '', '', '' ]))
// []
```

I think `removeFromEnd` can be improved as a higher-order function, much like `Array.prototype.filter`

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const removeFromEnd = (f = Boolean, [ x = Empty, ...xs ], cont = identity) =>
  x === Empty
    ? cont ([])
    : removeFromEnd (f, xs, end =>
        end.length === 0 && f (x)
          ? cont ([])
          : cont ([ x, ...end ]))

console.log (removeFromEnd (x => x === '', [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', false, 0 ]))
// [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', false, 0 ]

console.log (removeFromEnd (x => !x, [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', false, 0 ]))
// [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c' ]
```

For beginners, here is `removeFromEnd` expressed without fanciful ES6 destructuring syntaxes or arrow functions

```js
const identity = function (x)
{
  return x
}

const removeFromEnd = function (f = Boolean, xs = [], i = 0, cont = identity)
{
  if (i > xs.length)
    return cont ([])
  else
    return removeFromEnd (f, xs, i + 1, function (end) {
      if (end.length === 0 && f (xs [i]))
        return cont ([])
      else
        return cont ([ xs [i] ].concat (end))
    })
}

const data =
  [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', false, 0 ]

console.log (removeFromEnd (x => x === '', data))
// [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', false, 0 ]

console.log (removeFromEnd (x => !x, data))
// [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c' ]
```

The continuation-passing style used above might seem foreign to you, but it's essential if you want to write `removeFromEnd`:

1. with a proper [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)
2. with functional style using a pure expression

Reverting to imperative style, JavaScript allows us to write the program without the continuation complexity – however, the recursive call is no longer in tail position

I share this version of the program because most people that are new to functional thinking are coming from writing programs like this. Seeing the same program expressed in many different styles is something that always helped me tremendously. Maybe it can help you the same way ^^

```js
const removeFromEnd = function (f = Boolean, xs = [], i = 0)
{
  if (i > xs.length)
    return []
  
  const end =
    removeFromEnd (f, xs, i + 1)
    
  if (end.length === 0 && f (xs [i]))
    return []
  
  return [ xs [i] ] .concat (end)
}

const data =
  [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', false, 0 ]

console.log (removeFromEnd (x => x === '', data))
// [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', false, 0 ]

console.log (removeFromEnd (x => !x, data))
// [ 'a', 'b', '', 'c' ]
```

Comment: @Aaron that is a somewhat broad question: The `identity` function is the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) in the function monoid. When combining terms in functional style, we need some starting point. For example if we're combining numbers using addition, 0 is a good starting point because it will merely reflect the identity any other number it is combined with; `(5 + 0) == (0 + 5) == 5`. The identity function does the same thing - `compose(f, identity)` is equal to `compose(identity, f)` is equal to `f`

Comment: @Aaron More intuitively, you can think of the `identity` function as the empty (or default) value for variables of *Function* type. Compare `someFunc = x => x`  to `someInt = 0` or `someString = ""` or `someArr = []` or even `someObj = {}`. Thinking of functions as values that we can create, transform, and combine is the foundation of functional programming. In this context, a function is no different than any other ordinary type :D

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. The first one didn't quite make sense to me, but the second one did. So, you're saying that you use the `identity` function to signify that that parameter in the function expects a function. I visualised it as the last parameter in the reduce function - that's what you build your reduction on - an empty array, an empty string, etc.

Comment: Aaron, that's exactly right. And by assigning it as a default value to `cont`, we prevent the programmer from having to explicitly pass it in. Watch what happens when `cont` *is* specified in`removeFromEnd (x => x > 5, [ 1, 9, 5, 7, 9 ], console.log)` or `removeFromEnd (x => x > 5, [ 1, 9, 5, 7, 9 ], result => result.length)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use reduce and only add an element if it isn't an empty string or the array already has entries in it

```js
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '', 'c']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '']));

function removeFromEnd(arr) {
  return arr.reduceRight((a, b) => {
    if (b !== '' || a.length) a.push(b);
    return a;
  }, []).reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `reduceRight` and change one value when you find first elements that is not empty string.

```js
function removeFromEnd(arr) {
  return arr.reduceRight((r, e) => {
    if (e) r.match = true;
    if (r.match) r.arr.unshift(e)
    return r;
  }, {arr: []}).arr
}

console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '', 'c']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the array and remove elements until you reach a non empty string.

Here is an example:

```js
function removeFromEnd(arr){
   return arr.reverse().filter(function(v){
     if(v !== ""){
        this.stopRemoving = true;
     }
     return this.stopRemoving;
   }, {stopRemoving: false}).reverse();
}


console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '', 'c']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '']));
```

And here is an example using a classic loop

```js
function removeFromEnd(arr){
   for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
     if(arr[i] !== ""){
       break;
     }
     arr.pop();
   }
   return arr;
}


console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '', 'c']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '']));
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way that does not require all these ifs? Can I do it without creating in-memory copy of array?

Probably not very functional, but a very straight forward implementation:

```js
function removeFromEnd(arr) {
    let i = arr.length - 1;

    while (arr[i] === "") i--;

    return arr.slice(0, i + 1);
}

console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['a', '', '']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '', 'c']));
console.log(removeFromEnd(['', '', '', '']));
```

It's hard to find the balance here... You tagged `functional-programming`, and the answer by @naomik shows you a beautiful functional solution that matches both the tag and the concern in the quote.

If you're just looking to simplify and optimize, my snippet here might just be enough...